# Review queue - when to use no action needed or do an edit?

Tags: discussion, edits, review

Earlier today I came across a question in the review queue. The code was correctly formatted, but there were some obvious errors in grammar that I corrected.

I'm not sure whether I would have done this edit if I'd just come across the question, but I didn't want to mark this review task with a no action needed. So I accept that it was a borderline edit and I'm not ranting about it being rejected - I would really like to know:

If getting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17066150/806549) question as a review task, what is the proper action? No action or an edit? And if you choose to edit, what would be the proper edit?

My suggested edit is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2301096) for reference. (And I have noticed that I missed the error in the headline).

Comment: I have just edited the question myself.  I have fixed a number of issues that you did not, but should have if you had decided to edit it.  See the revision history to see what they specifically are.

Comment: Thanks for the input. @Servy missed the headline too, though. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion you didn't go far enough. "Please suggest solution" ?? Questions don't need that. Fixing spelling mistakes in stilted wording? Fix the wording. That question does need editing, but not like that. If you have figured out what the OP is asking, edit the question so the rest of us can get what is asked without having to figure it out.

Also, part of your review should have been leaving a comment to the OP begging for their SELECT statement. Expecting people to tell you how to change something based only on its output is a classic beginner mistake.

Comment: Without the select I'm even inclined to vote to close, due to it being incomplete